# if else statement execution

Tags: java

I am new to programming. When I run the code below, it executes only the if statement and prints only the "xmap". But my input has both 'x' and 'y' and so I want my program to crawl through every line and see if 'x' or'y' and print both. Can anyone help me with this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class abc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> xMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        Map<String, List<String>> yMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/"));

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] column = nextLine.split(":");
                if (column[0].equals("x")) {
                    if (column.length == 4) {
                        xMap.put(column[1], Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
                    } else {
                        yMap.put(column[1], Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
                    }
                }

            }
            scanner.close();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(xMap);
        System.out.println(yMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note, convention wise, a class should start with upper case. `public class Abc`

Comment: Show us your input file.

Answer (score 1):

It prints the xmap *if the input is x and it has 4 columns*. It will print the ymap *if the input is x (again!) and it has not 4 columns*

Maybe, that's what you want instead:

```
if (column[0].equals("x")) {
    if (column.length == 4) {
        xMap.put(column[1], Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
    } 
else if (column[0].equals("y")){
    if (column.length == 4) {
        yMap.put(column[1], Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variation,

```
if (column.length == 4) {
    if (column[0].equals("x")) {
        xMap.put(column[1], Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
    }
    else if (column[0].equals("y")){
        yMap.put(column[1], Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
    }
}
```

Yet another variation,

```
if (column.length == 4 && column[0].equals("x")) {
    xMap.put(column[1], Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
}
else if (column.length == 4 && column[0].equals("y")){
    yMap.put(column[1], Arrays.asList(column[2], column[3]));
}
```